# string with html tags to be values in hidden type input

Tags: php, html, string

I have a string that has a value with an html tag and this string I want to put in a hidden input type. This is for now:

```
$str = "som'e text <img src="img/src.jpg">.. <a href="link">link</a>";
echo '<input type="hidden" name="val" value="'.$str.'">';
```

I did this in order for it to be saved in my database to be show again, but the issue is it looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="val" value="som'e text <img src="img/src.jpg">.. <a href="link">link</a>">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use base64_encode and then decode the string while saving to database.

Comment: The keyword is "real_escape_string"
It's up to your database and php version.
see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

Try `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()` php [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).

```
<?php    
$str = "som'e text <img src=\"img/src.jpg\">.. <a href=\"link\">link</a>";
echo '<input type="hidden" name="val" value="'.base64_encode($str).'">';
```

and get the POST value as:

```
$val = base64_decode($_POST['val']);
```

[Remember to escape the strings properly]

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse quotes over and over within your string concatentator as they'll break the interpreter. Instead, escape the inner quotes with backslashes.

```
$str = "som'e text <img src=\"img/src.jpg\">.. <a href=\"link\">link</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `base64_encode()` for this.. and use `base64_decode()` for getting original text.

and I will highly recommend you to use `parameterized` way to insert in database if you are not using.. [PDO With Php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)